# Laurent expansion of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function

$$f(z) = \frac{e^z+1}{e^z-1}$$

This function has a Laurent expansion about $0$ of the form

$$f(z) = \frac{a}{z} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n$$

for constants $a, b_1,\ldots, b_n$. Show that $b_n=0$ for all even $n$.

---

What is the best way to do this? All I can think to do is find the laurent expansion and then show that a few are zero but obviously this doesn't prove it for all even $n$, just a few.

---

If we split $f(z)$ into even and odd parts we have

$$f(z) = \frac az +\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_{2k}z^{2k}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_{2k+1}z^{2k+1}$$

and how the problem turns into showing the first summation is zero.

Comment: How many coefficients in the power series do you need? it can be done without knowing the whole closed form of the series

Comment: @Joanpemo whoops I have realised I haven't put the full question down...

Comment: and $\displaystyle\frac{z}{e^z-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} z^k$ while $\displaystyle\frac{z e^z}{e^z-1} = \frac{-z}{e^{-z}-1} =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} (-z)^k$ hence $\displaystyle\frac{1}{z}\left(\frac{z}{e^z-1} + \frac{z e^z}{e^z-1} \right) = \frac{2}{z} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{k!} z^{2k}$ on $0 < |z| < 2 \pi$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function

Comment: @user1952009 These formulas don't seem correct to me. In your first one you have the LHS which has a Laurent series then on the RHS you have a taylor series with no negative powers. Same for the second. Please check before posting!!

Comment: $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ is holomorphic (analytic) on $|z| < 2 \pi$ (and at the last one I forgot to write $(2k)!$ instead of $k!$)

Comment: so it's the biter bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z)$ be the function given by

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{z}+1}{e^{z}-1}-\frac{2}{z}$$

Clearly $f(z)$ is analytic for $0<|z|<2\pi $.  Then, note that

$$\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=0$$

and $f(z)$ is analytic for all $|z|<2\pi$.  Furthermore, we have

$$\begin{align}
f(-z)&=\frac{e^{-z}+1}{e^{-z}-1}+\frac{2}{z}\\\\
&=-\frac{e^z+1}{e^z-1}+\frac{2}{z}\\\\
&=-f(z)
\end{align}$$

Hence, $f(z)$ is an odd function of $z$ and can be expanded in a Taylor series of odd powers only with $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^{2n-1}$.  Finally, we can write

$$\frac{e^{z}+1}{e^{z}-1}=\frac2z+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^{2n-1}$$

as was to be shown.

Comment: $f$ is not analytic for $z\ne 0.$ It has poles at $n2\pi i,$ $n$ a non-integer integer.

Comment: that should be "nonzero integer" in my first comment

Comment: @zhw. No worry.  I assumed that you knew (and meant to write) that.

Comment: @Mark Viola, please provide a formula for $a_n$.

Comment: @MichaelLevy There is no need to give a "formula" for $a_n$ to show that $f$ has a Laurent series that is expressed with only odd powers of $z$.

Comment: @Mark Viola, That is true. For completeness sake, it would be useful.

Answer (score 6):

Check that $f(-z) = -f(z).$ Thus

$$\frac{a}{-z} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(-z)^n = -\left (\frac{a}{z} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n\right ) = -\frac{a}{z} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-b_n)z^n.$$

Equating coefficients gives the desired result.

Comment: go through the simple computation -- f is odd

Comment: Succinctly written.  +1